# systemd keeps respawning pulseaudio, and doesn't allow me to stop it

Tags: linux, audio, systemd, pulse-audio

So I was trying to stop pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -k`, but it kept restarting "on its own", even though I have the configuration `autospawn = no` in place.

I'm pretty sure it's systemd that keeps restarting it, as instructed by /usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sound Service

[Service]
# Note that notify will only work if --daemonize=no
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
Also=pulseaudio.socket
WantedBy=default.target
```

But the thing is, when I try to stop this service with `systemctl stop pulseaudio.service`, systemctl returns me the following:

```
Failed to stop pulseaudio.service: Unit pulseaudio.service not loaded.
```

How do I stop/disable this service?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To stop user services it's necessary to use the parameter `--user`:

```
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service
```

Answer (score 1):

`systemctl --user mask pulseaudio.socket` helped me to make it not restart after killing it. changing autospawn and daemon-binary configs didn't help and disabling the service also didn't help.

source: https://winaero.com/blog/disable-pulseaudio-per-user-in-linux/

Also see https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/979

Answer (score 0):

In the files:

/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.socket

/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service

just below the line:

ConditionUser=!root

add:

ConditionUser=!gdm


That's it!